# How to find 4 numbers whose XOR is equal to zero in an array?

Tags: c, algorithm

Given an array `A[]` of size `n<=100000` and `0<=A[i]<=2^64`, and every two adjacent element of `A[]` have exactly one different digit in their binary representation. Now we have to check if there exist any `4` elements `A[i1],A[i2],A[i3] and A[i4]` in array such that `1<=i1<i2<i3<i4<=n` and `A[i1] xor A[i2] xor A[i3] xor A[i4] = 0`.

Comment: It would help if you told us what you had done so far.

Comment: I have no idea how to start. It would be a great help if you can suggest me some topic to go through before giving this problem a shot.

Comment: The solution should be apparent if you write our a 4 digit binary number, then a number following it that obeys the rule that only one digit changes (that rule is key). Then consider, how could you xor your way to 0 with two more numbers where each subsequent number can only change by one digit. You should see the pattern that you'll be looking for.

Comment: @btilly I posted an answer which will not work so it has been deleted. The failing assumption was that if (u,v) are separated by j steps, then (x,y) will also differ by j steps. This will not work since the bits toggled during the j steps need not be unique

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**  Under these rules, could two numbers XOR to be zero?  Why or why not?  What would those two numbers look like with regard to each other?

Comment: they must be equal i guess. no?

Comment: No.   I do not respond to queries using terms like "plz", "intr8sting", "knw".

Answer (score 4):

Since two adjacent numbers differ by a single binary bit, the result of XOR'ing two adjacent numbers together is very predictable:

`x` represents a bit whose value doesn't matter, but is the same as the corresponding `x` below/above it.

```
        xxxxxxxxxxxxx1xxxxxxxxxxxx
xor:    xxxxxxxxxxxxx0xxxxxxxxxxxx
__________________________________
        00000000000001000000000000
```

This is true for ANY two adjacent numbers in the set you described.

If you can find another pair of adjacent numbers, that differ by the same bit, they will ALSO XOR-out to the same value: `00000000000001000000000000`

And finally, XOR'ing those two values together will DEFINITELY give you a final answer of zero.

---

So the algorithm you want looks like:

- Identify which bit is different between a number and its successor (bit 0-63)
- Find another pair of numbers that also differ by the same bit identified in step 1.

Those are your 4 values.

Note that if N > 64, then by the [pigeonhole priniciple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there MUST be a solution like this.
If `N <= 64`, there *may* be a solution of this form, or a solution of another form, I didn't describe here.

*There are other constraints that could also find 4 numbers that xor together to 0.

But this is probably the simplest way to search for a solution.

Failing to find a solution this way does not guarantee that there is **no** solution, however.*

Comment: This method would fail, as finding two pairs of numbers that differ by the _same_ bit (as in a single bit, as you described) violates the original constraint that (A[a1] < A[a2] < A[a3] < A[a4]). Finding two pairs of numbers that differ by the same _group of bits_, on the other hand, yields a _range_ of numbers that can be ordered, allowing the constraint (A[a1] < A[a2] < A[a3] < A[a4]) to be upheld.

Comment: @aps:  10101 and 10001 differ by the middle bit.  Numbers 10100 and 10000 also differ by the middle bit.   10000 < 10001 < 10100 < 10101.

Comment: @albenky So they do. I stand corrected. +1 for technical accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Look at the truth table for XOR:

```
A | B | Output
- + - + - - - 
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

Now, what binary number XORs with 10101 to be 0?

Those are the types of numbers to look for.

Edit:
Once you find out what the relationship between those numbers are, which you seem to have from your comment on @abelenky 's answer, you have to look at the other parts of the problem. Since each adjacent element has exactly one different digit in their binary representation, what does that mean about the likelihood that two adjacent elements are what we are looking for?

Comment: If I am getting it right then we have to check if there is a pair of adjacent numbers (a,b) and (c,d) following given constraints and (a^b==c^d). Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question from a currently running algorithmic competition at CodeChef.
The link the the question being http://www.codechef.com/JULY12/problems/GRAYSC .So it is the usage of unfair means and the question should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Make Some careful observations about all possible values of xor of two adjacent numbers, in total how many **distinct** values are possible? Once you figure this out you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** if you are completely stuck, then try the O(n^4) solution:

```
for i = 0 to N-3
  for j = i+1 to N-2
    for k = j+1 to N-1
      for l = k+1 to N
         if a[i] XOR a[j] XOR a[k] XOR a[l] is equal to 0 then
           print a[i], a[j], a[k], a[l]
```

Comment: ... and for N == 100000, you could examine all the possibilities by hand over a nice cup of tea and come up with the answer in less time that it would take this algorithm to complete... :-)